# Difference between Chatter Plus and Employee Community

Tags: chatter, customer-community, community

Chatter Plus and Employee community seem to be very similar licenses.

[image: Chatter Plus Community]

1. Is there a general difference between Chatter Plus and Employee Community?
2. Do they have the same object permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is 3 options:
- Chatter Plus
- Employee Community
- force.com license

Differences:
- force.com allows to create or edit accounts and contacts, while chatter/community are read only on account/contact
- all 3 licenses share a common limit on 10 custom objects
- none of the 3 license types grants access to opportunity, pricebook, product, order -> need a full CRM license to work on those objects
- employee portals allows users to issue their own cases or review cases

so in other words:
- if you are not running your internal ticket management over SF (using case) and don't need to create account/contact go for cheapest license, which is chatter plus
- otherwise one of the two others