# Chatter feed for employee community vs. Chatter Plus Users

Tags: chatter, community, employee-community

**Background:**

As pointed out in my question regarding [Employee Community vs. Chatter Plus](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65862/difference-between-chatter-plus-and-employee-community) the major difference between Chatter Plus and Employee Community is that Chatter Users can access salesforce via login.salesforce.com while Employee Community users have to use a community (portal) login.

After the implementation of a customer community, Salesforce allows you to decide whether or not a chatter post is shared with "all users" or "[your company name] only". (see figure 1)

[image: Figure 1 Share Chatter Post]

*Figure 1*

**Scenerio**

A customer community, a partner and a employee community are in place. An internal user wants to share a post with all employees (employee community and standard salesforce users).

**Questions**

1. Is it possible, as a employee community user, to share a post with internal user but not with customer and partner community users?
2. Is it possible, as a standard salesforce user, to share posts with all employees?
3. It the chatter feed of a Chatter Plus User the same as the feed of an employee community user?

Answer (score 1):

These have been very challenging to answer and understand. Best way is to try it out with various users with different roles (internal, community, employee community).

Here are some answers to your questions from my experience on these:

1. If the internal user has access to employee community, he can see the post once he logs into employee community. The EC member can mention them(not very sure).
2. This is possible through Groups. The Employee Community should have a group where all members are present.
3. No its not same. Feeds are accessible only through groups or within the same community.

Some very helpful links are below. Please go through and understand more about this.

[Linking the chatter feeds between partner/customer communities with the Internal chatter feed.](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000187275&language=en_US)

[Who Can See What in Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_visibility.htm&language=en_US)

[Unable to @mention Partner user on chatter feed by Salesforce Internal User](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17605/unable-to-mention-partner-user-on-chatter-feed-by-salesforce-internal-user)